# use of matplotlib.imshow() without "Clipping input data to the valid range"

Tags: image, pixel, imshow

I'm using matplotlib.imshow() with students to learn basic image processing. But if a student make an error, i would like python to show a warning instead of correcting it automatically.

For exemple : if a pixel value of the image we are working on is more than 255, i would like python displays a warning and stop the program, but instead of that, the imshow() method put the data to 255 for all the pixels up to 255.

does exist a option in the imshow() method to stop the programm when a pixel value is wrong ?

Thanks for answering me.

I tried to use options of the cmap parameter, but there is a lot, and i didn't find a cmap satisfying option.

Comment: `imshow` is intended for showing images, and there is no such thing as wrong pixel value when using `imshow` (even NaN value doesn't show a warning).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.